# Android: getApplicationContext()

Tags: java, android

Estou a tentar fazer

```
Database db = new Database(this.getApplicationContext());
```

Onde Database é uma classe que tenho com os todos os metodos relacionados com Base de Dados e que estou a chamar para preencher uma ExpandableList. No entanto, estou a obter erro no **this**, o erro é "`Cannot referenced from a static context`".
Como posso obter o context de forma a não obter este erro?

```
public class ExpandableList {

public static HashMap<String, List<String>> getData() {
    HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();


    List<String> exemplos = new ArrayList<String>();
    Database db = new Database(this.getApplicationContext());
(...)
```

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski obrigada!! Se quiseres mete como resposta q aceito!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pode passar via parametro:

```
getData(ApplicationContext appContext)
```

**getApplicationContext()** é um método da Activity, então só existe em Classes que Estendem de Activity (AppCompatActivity, ActionBarActivity, entre outras)

tente o seguinte:

```
    public static HashMap<String, List<String>> getData(ApplicationContext appContext) {
    // conteudo do seu metodo 
Database db = new Database(appContext);
    }
```

Já na sua Activity:

```
expandableList.getData(this.getApplicationContext());
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Saudações!